# Printing a line of dots and two other symboles that represent answers

Tags: java

I need to create a line with 100 dots but with 2 symbols at different places. One is a "X" which is the real answer and the other is a "O" which represent the users guess. The real answer ("X") is a random variable and the users guess ("O") is the input of the user.

It has to look like this:
..............................O.............................X.......................................

I just need a bit of help starting off. The rest of the project is already finished but this is just the finishing touch and I'm not sure how to continue. I've tried using an array but without success. Thanks!

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on how to ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

Very pedestrian, straight forward solution:

```
String foo(int answer, int guess, int size) {
    char[] line = new char[size];
    Arrays.fill(line, '.');
    line[answer] = 'X';
    line[guess] = 'O';
    return new String(line);
}
```

Comment: Nice; except for naming - why not call it "generateDottedLine()" or something. Why call it foo when it is very clear what it should be doing?!

Comment: The method name is subjective and easily changed.

Comment: And you are trying to give an answer for "eternity"; and thus: lead by example. **naming** is one of the most important aspects of programming.

Comment: @GhostCat that's precisely why I called it 'foo'.  Please see [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/69788/what-is-the-history-of-the-use-of-foo-and-bar-in-source-code-examples).  (Particularly [this answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/69793))

Comment: Lets agree that we disagree. foo/bar are "useful" names when writing example code that only exists to "show" some concept as code. But: your method has a dedicated purpose. It has a well defined meaning. There is no point in giving it a no-name. You see, foo/bar gives the impression that names don't matter. But they do!

Comment: @GhostCat foo/bar are meta-syntactic placeholders that should always be replaced in production code **because** names matter.  Your assumption that any naming choice I make (like "generateDottedLine" or something) would be a good name "for eternity" is fundamentally flawed

Comment: You assume that a newbie (who has hard time printing a line with 100 dots in it) can follow your logic?! If my logic is flawed; well, your's ain't much better. But as said; lets agree that we disagree.

Answer (score 0):

Some pseudo-code to get you started.

```
int userGuess = ... user giving you input
int randomTarget = ... some random number

for (int i=0; i < 100; i++) {
  if (i == userGuess) print "O"
  else if (i == randomTarget) print "X"
       else print "."
```

And for the record: you need to figure what to print when userGuess==randomTarget !

Java code is left to the reader as exercise!

Answer (score 0):

This uses a Java IntStream instead of a loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int answer = 57;
    int guess = 14;

    IntStream.range(0, 100).forEach(i -> {
      if (i == answer)
      {
        System.out.print('X');
      }
      else if (i == guess)
      {
        System.out.print('O');
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.print('.');
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: I wouldnt suggest streams to an absolute beginner. I guess he will have enough difficulties to cope with an ordinary for loop.